# SQL Select from multiple tables return what is available

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pdo, innodb

I have three tables, one for users, one for images, and one that maps the images to the users. Here is my query (simplified):

```
"SELECT * FROM tb_users u, tb_images i, tb_mapimagestousers m
    WHERE
u.id = :userid
    AND
m.userid = u.id
    AND
i.id = m.imgid
```

This query will return fine as long as there is data to pull from all tables. If there is no image assigned to a user there will be no entry for them in the images or the mapimagestousers tables, and the query will return an empty set (understandably). How do I query the database so that, in the case of no assigned image, I still get whatever I pulled from the users table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Then you would know about outer joins.

You want:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_users u LEFT JOIN
     tb_mapimagestousers miu
     ON miu.userid = u.id LEFT JOIN
     tb_images i
     ON miu.imgid = i.id
WHERE u.id = :userid;
```

Comment: When you string those joins together does it treat all the results returned so far as a single table? So if I were to do a bunch of left joins and then a right join, that right join would treat the entire string of left joins as a single table, in terms of the way it combines the results, right?

Comment: And any particular reason why not to use commas in the `FROM` clause?

Comment: Because the correct SQL syntax is to use explicit `JOIN`s.  Commas are just a holdover from the original language defined in the 1970s and 1980s.